# How to fix issue when run Magento update command?

Tags: magento2.4, issue

I changed php version and composer version.But run command "bin/magento setup:upgrade", display error like this.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '584362' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`url_rewrite_id`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento added a constraint to the table `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` at 2.4.3 I think.

You won't be able to bin/magento setup:upgrade without solving the issue.
Composer is not at fault.

The fix is pretty easy.

Take full backup of your database first and execute this SQL query.

```
START TRANSACTION; CREATE TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_temp 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM catalog_url_rewrite_product_category; ALTER TABLE 
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category RENAME 
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_backup; ALTER TABLE 
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_temp RENAME 
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category; DROP TABLE 
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category_backup; COMMIT;
```

Github issue. (Above solution is from there)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33770

Solution Explanation:
We take all DISTINCT data from catalog_url_rewrite_product_category so no more duplicate url_rewrite_id rows and add it to a temp table.

We rename the table `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category` to a temp name
We rename the temp table that we stored the DISTINCT data back to the name of the original table of `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`.

Magento adds all the required constraints/relations/indexes etc to the new table via the declarations in db_schema.xml on `bin/magento setup:upgrade` process.

Hope it helps